# Spring-boot: google sheets download from URL

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, url, download

I have to develop a REST-ful Web Service with Spring boot (Java). 
It will download a file from an URL, I should get a .csv file from a Google Sheets url.

The URL is "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT6GDZNWIJgVmd3GLlEL4dPA-B_VkatLA--B4EPWhvTYRs8u244QXeaE8Ij7ikJsuUj9oyBnvH6OAGL/pub?gid=67122230/u0026amp;single=true/u0026amp;output=csv" (I found it after a JSON file parsing).

Can someone help me to find some examples? I don't really know how to start.
I'm trying but I'm only getting .csv file with HTML inside.

Comment: In order to download the Spreadsheet as a CSV data, how about modifying the URL to ``https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT6GDZNWIJgVmd3GLlEL4dPA-B_VkatLA--B4EPWhvTYRs8u244QXeaE8Ij7ikJsuUj9oyBnvH6OAGL/pub?gid=67122230&single=true&output=csv``?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. That definitely works. But I have a problem: I can't change the URL by myself, because my application finds by itself the URL after a JSON parsing. How can I solve this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not the direct solution.